# Как создать http-сервер с помощью Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как мне создать http-сервер, который будет работать на порту `9999` и занимается следующей задачей:

- Анализирует аргумент коллбека `request`, а именно его свойство `headers`.
- В ответ присылает все значения из `headers` в формате:

  ```
  name: value
  name: value
  ```
- Content-Type должен быть выставлен как `text/plain`?

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function (request,responce) {
    responce.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain, charset=utf-8');
    responce.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain', {name: +'value\n'});
    responce.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain', {name: +'value\n'});
    responce.end('ok');
});

const port = 9999;

server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Приведите ваши попытки

Comment: @entithat Незнаю начал ли я правильно или нет,но я дальше незнаю что написать,вообще не уверен в своем "коде" . Добавил свой код в описание к вопросу

Comment: а что, этот код разве не работает?

Comment: было ж правильно почти

Comment: Не пытайтесь угадывать на этом уровне. Читайте описание языка и API. Пробуйте примеры еще меньше (угадывайте там). Вы должны понимать, как работает каждая из наименьших деталей по-отдельности. Когда вы сможете правильно сказать, что делает программа-пример до ее запуска, тогда вы действительно поняли.

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   response.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain');
  
   let value='';
   const requestHeaders = request.headers;
   for (const name in requestHeaders) {
      value = value + name +':'+ requestHeaders[name]+ '\n';
   }
   response.end(value); 
   
});

const port = 9999;
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так через ":":

```
const data = Object.entries(request.headers).map(pair=>pair.join(": ")).join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать `http-server` в принципе не сложно, но реализовать полноценную работу сервера с обработчиками запросов, событий, данных, ошибок и т.п. - задача трудоемкая и затрагивает очень много тем, глубокого познания Node.js и принципы работы с [потоками](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), [событиями](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html), [сокетами](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket), [состоянием](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/state), [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) / [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) протоколами и многого другого.

[Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536730/how-to-respond-to-post-request-in-node-js/63537571#63537571) можете посмотреть один из примеров реализации серверной части без каких либо фреймворков. Ну или можете реализовать свой сервер с помощью [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/ru/) или [Nest.js](https://nestjs.com/)